# Jboss6.1 - Enable Jmx port for monitoring heap AS via Zabbix

Tags: jboss, monitoring, jmx

Could you help me enable jmx port for Jboss6.1. I tried added many options to start script my application, but this is didn't help.

My last attempt was like:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl"

JBOSS_CLASSPATH="../lib/jboss-logmanager.jar"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9002"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.244.222.201"
```

Jboss just didn't start after this.

Version Jboss from log:  JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8)

Comment: And I don't have some logs from jboss. Create only GC logs gc_2018-07-19-14-47.log.0.current. server.log is empty.

Comment: now I have error: WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager

ERROR: JBAS014612: Operation ("parallel-extension-add") failed - address: ([])

java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014670: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fixed problem after added

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9002"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.6.194.242"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:/app/jboss-eap-6.1/lib/jboss-logmanager-1.4.0.Final-redhat-1.jar"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:/app/jboss-eap-6.1/lib/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:/app/jboss-eap-6.1/lib/log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar"
```

and

JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.logmanager"
Now I have another error, but this new story. 
ps. New error:
2018-07-19 17:47:40,716 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "logging"),
    ("console-handler" => "CONSOLE")